# Sharing observer function code between mutable and frozen versions of a type

Tags: haskell, immutability

I was working on creating my own custom mutable/frozen data type that internally contains an `MVector`/`Vector`. It needs to be mutable for performance reasons so switching to an immutable data structure is not something I am considering.

It seems like implementing an observer function for one of the two versions should allow me to just steal that implementation for the other type. Here are the two options I am considering:

```
render :: Show a => MCustom s a -> ST s String
render mc = ...non trivial implementation...

show :: Show a => Custom a -> a
show c = runST $ render =<< unsafeThaw c
```

Where `unsafeThaw` calls `Vector.unsafeThaw` under the covers, which should be safe as that thawed vector is never mutated, only read. This approach feels the cleanest, the only downside is that `render` is strict, which forces `show` to be strict whereas a duplicate implementation could correctly stream the String without forcing it all at once.

The other option, which feels much more dirty but that I think is safe is to do this:

```
show :: Show a => Custom a -> a
show c = ...non trivial implementation that allows lazy streaming...

render :: Show a => MCustom s a -> ST s String
render mc = do
    s <- show <$> unsafeFreeze mc
    s `deepseq` pure s
```

Are either of these my best option? If not what else should I do?

To me it seemed most intuitive to build one version off of the other. But it seems like if I make the mutable version the base version then I will end up with a lot more strictness then I want, even if the implementations seem fairly clean and logical, just because `ST` necessitates strictness unless I throw in some `unsafeInterleaveST` calls, but these would only be safe when the mutable observer was called via an immutable object.

On the other hand if I make the immutable version the base version then I will end up with more dirty, `deepseq` code, and sometimes I would just have to reimplement things. For example all in place editing functions can be done on a frozen object pretty easily by just copying the frozen object and then calling `unsafeThaw` on it and modifying the copy in place before calling `unsafeFreeze` and returning it. But doing the opposite isn't really doable, as a copy modification that is used for the immutable version cannot be converted to an in place modification.

Should I perhaps write all modification functions alongside the mutable implementation, and all observer functions alongside the immutable implementation. And then have a file that depends on both that unifies everything via `unsafeThaw` and `unsafeFreeze`?

Comment: Why even `unsafeThaw` in the first version if the vector isn't mutated?

Comment: Taking a cue from `vector`, you should probably implement the pure version of `show` (which should intrinsically be a pure operation, and should anyways be needing to evaluate most/all of the structure) and if you really want you can pass it over to the mutable version via `unsafeFreeze`, `unsafeThaw`. I'm quite confused as to why you need the `deepseq` call in `render`.

Comment: There is no reason a lazy show could not exist for the mutable type, having type e.g. `Show a => MCustom s a -> a` - if you build your immutable type atop your mutable one, your immutable functions will typically just wrap the mutable ones which are safe to use in that context.

Comment: @AndrásKovács Because otherwise calling `render` doesn't type check, I can only use `render` on the thawed version.

Comment: @Alec because the function is not safe without `deepseq`: `v <- MV.replicate 1 0`, `s <-  show <$> V.unsafeFreeze v`, `MV.write v 0 1`, `putStrLn s` incorrectly prints `[1]` whereas I want `[0]`. With `deepseq` I correctly get `[0]`.

Comment: @user2407038 Can you give me a safe implementation of such a lazy show? Because as you can see from my other comment just using `unsafeFreeze` and not `deepseq` is unsafe. And `deepseq` ruins laziness for obvious reasons.

Comment: @semicolon Maybe you should just not have a `Show` instance for the mutable version of your data structure then. `MVector` doesn't have such an instance, for example.

Comment: @Alec `Show` was just one example. The same question applies to tons of operations from indexing to slicing to folding.

Comment: @Alec Also I really want a `render` that I can use while in the `ST` monad, manually calling `unsafeFreeze` each time sounds like a bad idea, and I don't want to pay for `freeze`.

Comment: @semicolon I can't, because I haven't a clue what `MCustom` or `Custom` look like. The `show` function seems straightforward if you have a function `readMVal :: MCustom s a -> Ix -> a` , presumably the version for `Custom` would use a comparable `Custom a -> Ix -> a` to read individual 'parts' of the structure and combine the result in some way.

Comment: @user2407038 MCustom / Custom are just MVector and Vector with some extra STRef's on them. Do you see why `show` for a mutable object HAS to be strict? Because otherwise if you don't request the pure output string fully before you mutate the structure you will change the value of that "pure" string. Now that we have established the mutable version HAS to be strict, how do I go about sharing code most efficiently, because the immutable version's `show` should be lazy, I think I have to use `unsafeFreeze` and `deepseq`.

Answer (score 0):

How about having a pure function

```
show :: (StringLike s, Show a) => Custom a -> s
```

You can get both lazy and strict output with different instantiations of `s`, in which `cons` is either lazy or strict; e.g. `String` or `Text`:

```
class StringLike s where 
  cons :: Char -> s -> s 
  nil :: s 
  uncons :: s -> Maybe (Char, s) 

instance StringLike String where ...
instance StringLike Text where ...
```

You could use other methods, e.g. phantom types, or simply having two functions (`showString` and `showText`), to distinguish between lazy and strict output if you like. But if you look at types as specifications of a function's semantics, then the place to indicate laziness or strictness is in the return type of that operation. This removes the need for some sort of strict `show` for `Custom` inside of `ST`.

For the `MCustom` version, you probably do not export the `String` version, e.g:

```
render :: MCustom s a -> ST s Text
render a = show <$> unsafeFreeze a
```

You can throw in a `seq` to force the result when the function runs but the entire `Text` would be forced when any character is used anyways.

---

But the simplest solution seems to just abstract the pattern of using a mutable structure in an immutable fashion, e.g.

```
atomically :: (NFData a) => (Custom x -> a) -> MCustom s x -> ST s a 
atomically f v = do
    r <- f <$> unsafeFreeze v
    r `deepseq` pure r
```

This saves you from using `unsafeFreeze/deepseq` all over your code, just as you have [`modify`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.11.0.0/docs/src/Data-Vector.html#modify) to do immutable operations on mutable vectors.

Comment: `render` is not safe, because if you don't force with `seq` before returning then you can have the exact same issue as above. If you mutate the vector before you force ANY of the returned string, then the underlying text will be mutated out from under you, and thus it isn't pure / safe. `atomically` seems like a decent abstraction, but doesn't solve the main issue which is that I am forced to have some combination of bidirectional coupling, code duplication / excessive strictness. As writes would still have to be specified in the mutable module, and reads in the immutable module.

Comment: So since `render` still requires `seq`, you really haven't gained much from just using `String` and then `deepseq` instead, and you have a more complex result that requires more code.

Comment: It seems to me that bidirectional coupling is baked in on a very basic level - some algorithms are fundamentally mutable and others immutable (and others are sensible in both contexts). With atomically/modify I dont think you would have code duplication, nor excessive strictness (youve made clear that all MCustom functions should be strict). Is it really necessary to permit reading only from the immutable type and writing only to the mutable one?

Comment: Ignoring laziness everything you can do with a immutable type you can do with a mutable type, reading writing etc (you just have to do it in ST and be careful about accidental sharing). So I was hoping to have the mutable type be the "core" structure and the immutable type be a pure wrapper over the top. Which only breaks in one circumstance, which is that the pure wrapper should be more lazy than the impure core type. The exception to this is when you have a type you can mutate without total copying, such as trees / linked lists, then you want the two versions fairly separate.

Comment: "Is it really necessary to permit reading only from the immutable type and writing only to the mutable one" oh no I didn't mean that. I mean that I could potentially write all the potentially lazy read operations on the immutable type, and all the strict write operations on the mutable type. Within `Custom.Base` and `MCustom.Base`. Then I would have `Custom` which would use `unsafeThaw` to get write operations, and `MCustom` which would use `unsafeFreeze` and `deepseq` to get read operations. Then I wouldn't bother importing from the limited `.Base` modules any more and get all operations.